# Can a github ReadMe.md be different in different master branches of same product?

Tags: git, github, readme

I develop in my master branch. My colleagues develop in their personal master branches. We merge it into organisation master branch (this simplifies AppVeyor, TravisCI and other services use, also allows to have parallel branches devoted only for documentation for each developer). Merge of ReadMe.md is a pain. Is it possible to:

- not automerge ReadMe.md file?
- make parts of the ReadMe.md conditional (eg if ReadMe is in B/master do this and if it is in B/master do that)?

Comment: Google merge strategies like `--ours`

Answer (score 5):

There are strategies for working around this (`git merge --strategy ours`, `git update-index --assume-unchanged`), but they'll still retain a maintenance burden.  A better option is to rethink your requirements: why are you making local-specific changes to a global file?

Configuration should generally be consistent across all developers, especially if you're using versioned development environments through something like Vagrant.  If you have notes that really are specific (e.g. a TODO list to remind yourself to do certain things), then that should go in a separate, untracked file.

Comment: Imo the original question is reasonable.  GitHub's branch page shows *only* the readme.md file, but as you say this is a *global* file, not a branch-specific file.

I would appreciate either of the following improvements to GitHub branch pages:

1. Add a section to GitHub branch pages allowing devs to describe the branch in whatever detail they like.

2. Show a *branch specific* file, say branch.md, instead of readme.md if branch.md exists.

Comment: @EdwardK.Ream Generally git works best without long-lived branches.  In that case, you don't need much description of a branch, because it only has a very few changes, and what you do need can be described in a related ticket (for instance, when using Jira, you can put the ticket identifier in the branch name and configure auto-linking).